# injecting/embedding code in a PDF file?

Tags: javascript, pdf, exe

Is it possible to combine exe with PDF, so that on opening that PDF, exe runs and gives a message Hello World !
Can i edit PDF structure, and combine my exe or my code in the object part of the PDF structure ?

[Here is the image of the PDF document structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTlQA.png)

Comment: This cannot be done, think of the massive security implications of this! No one would ever open another PDF in their lives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what George said is not exactly true, it's just not possible in a legitimate use of the standard and the software, from a hacky point of view, running code from a file is actually possible since PDF is a format created by men and so are the readers, so, it is vulnerable (invulnerable software doesn't exist).

In this case, you would have to find a vulnerability, either in the format itself (stepping out of the sandbox) or in the tools it needs to be displayed (Adobe reader, Google Chrome PDF Viewer, etc) so you can execute arbitrary code on the machine once the file is opened.
This gives you dozens of libraries, code pieces, software and standards involved and to work with, and believe me, there's a hole somewhere.

Today, there's no such vulnerabilty (we dont know about it), but it doesn't mean it doesn't exists, it's just not discovered/reported yet.

As temporary solution, and knowing that this kind of things are illegal if you pretend to use them to distribute malware, you could [camuflate your binary](https://prdeving.wordpress.com/2017/02/08/camouflating-windows-malware/) with a PDF icon and play with the extension so you can do it undetectable to non-tech windows users.

Comment: Well, my aim is not to distribute the malware or propagate any worm.
I am just trying to understand the structure of PDF document completely, for this somehow i want to play a little with it.
Thanks ! PRDeving !

Comment: In that case, read the PDF specifications as @phihag said http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf :)

Answer (score 2):

If that were possible, it would be a serious security hole; as a user, you would risk infecting your computer with malware every time you view a PDF!

You can use `/Type /EmbeddedFile` to attach a file into a PDF file; see §7.11.4 of the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). However, this file will only be executed if the user extracts it and runs it.

You can also add JavaScript code to your document; see §12.6.4.16. However, this code runs in a sandbox.

Comment: Well, i am exploring it, as i am trying to understand the PDF file structure, ultimate goal is to play with the PDF file structure and try to put some hacks in it !
Thanks for the information Phihag !